# System.OperationCanceledException : dotnet Core 2.1

Tags: .net-core, circleci

I am trying to setup a xunit project for my integration testing, it calls our local test server instead of the local host .

Whenever I run my project locally it is working fine .

But when I tried to integrate with circleCI I am getting below exception

```
Starting test execution, please wait...
```

Hello
[xUnit.net 00:01:41.45]     IntegrationTesting.Test1.LTest1 [FAIL]
Failed   IntegrationTesting.Test1.LTest1
Error Message:
 System.OperationCanceledException : The operation was canceled.
Stack Trace:
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.HandleFinishSendAsyncError(Exception e, CancellationTokenSource cts)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts)
   at IntegrationTesting.Test1.LTest1() in /root/project/Testing/Test1.cs:line 29
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

Here is the sample code

```
 [Fact]
 public async Task LTest1()
{


     _client = new HttpClient();

    _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer","asdsada");

    Console.WriteLine("Hello");

    var response = await _client.GetAsync("https://testServer/api/work");

    var testdata = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    Console.WriteLine(testdata);

}
```